# C++ Input Function prematurely closing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include "UI.h"
using namespace std;
int UI::Input(){
    int KeyPressed = 777; //Doesn't matter being intialized
    if (kbhit()){//Fix???
        KeyPressed  = getch();
    } /End Fix???
    if ( KeyPressed == 0 || KeyPressed == 224 ){//
        KeyPressed = 256 + getch();
    }
    if (KeyPressed == Left){
        return 1;
    } else if (KeyPressed == Right){
        return 2;
    } else if (KeyPressed == Up){
        return 3;
    } else if (KeyPressed == Down){
        return 4;
    } else if (KeyPressed == Pause){
        return 5;
    } else if (KeyPressed == Accept){
        return 6;
    } else if (KeyPressed == Cancel){
        return 7;
    } else if (KeyPressed == Menu){
        return 8;
    }
    return -9;//No input
 }
```

So this function is not returning anything when used in code. I am using Visual Studio.

As far as I can tell if I put a break point at the beginning of my if statements it never is even reached. For some reason the line about with getch() is doing something to my function but I can't figure out what.

Any advice to explain why my function isn't making it to the if statements be appreciated.

Ok I feel stupid found the fix for now. Will confirm if still works after feature creep

Comment: So, this is a console application?

Comment: Maybe the function itself is never reached. Try putting a break point at the beginning of the function and then *stepping* from there to see what really happens. If you've got this far using the debugger it should be easy enough to figure this out.

Comment: Its a console app .
I can put the breakpoint at the "KeyPressed = getch();" line then if go next step it goes into the getch() function code and then after about 15 steps it just stops and ends programs with not jumping onto the next line of the function. No errors occur just ends as far as I can tell and doesn't assign anything to KeyPressed.

Comment: And if you put a break point on the "KeyPressed = getch();" line, the breakpoint hits and you can step over that statement?

Comment: when I step over it assigns a large negative value (assuming because no input) and then tries the line again then it abandons the function.

Could it be that no input will cause the function to do a break type reaction? Sorry I can't find any good documentation on the function just examples of it in use.